# What is wrong with this IF ELSE Statement

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement

What is wrong with this code?
I am trying to run this but every time i run this i get this error:

> else if array[i] == "d" or array [i] == "f" or array[i]  == "g":
>
> Syntax Error: invalid syntax

I have tried everything but can't fix it. Please Help me, and thank you in advance.

```
input = "ypyoz"
array =[]
alphabet = [" ","b","c","d", "f","g","h","j","k","l","m","n","p","q","r","s","t","v","w","x","y","z"]
for i in range(len(input)):
    array.append(input[i])

for i in range(len(array)):
    if array[i] in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
        array[i] = array[i]
    else:
        if array[i] == "b" or array[i] == "c":
            vowel = "a"
        else if array[i] == "d" or array[i] == "f" or array[i] == "g":
            vowel = "e"
        else if array[i] == "h" or array[i] == "j" or array[i] == "k" or array[i] == "l":
            vowel = "i"
        else if array[i] == "m" or array[i] == "n" or array[i] == "p" or array[i] == "q" or array[i] == "r":
            vowel = "o"
        else if array[i] == "s" or array[i] == "t" or array[i] == "v" or array[i] == "w" or array[i] == "x" or array[i] == "y" or array[i] == "z":
            vowel = "u" 
        consenent = alphabet.index(array[i])


        array[i] = array[i] + vowel + alphabet[consenent + 1]
print ''.join(array)
```

Comment: Python's equivalent of `else if` is `elif`.

Comment: There is no `else if` in python...it's `elif` ...

Comment: I wonder what's the source of motivitation behind the up vote here?

Comment: Not related to the question but `array[i] == "s" or array[i] == "t" or array[i] == "v" or array[i] == "w" or array[i] == "x" or array[i] == "y" or array[i] == "z"` can be replaced with `array[i] in ('s', 't', 'v', 'w', 'y', 'z')` and `array[i] = array[i]` does nothing`.

Comment: Also, parentheses are your friend.

Comment: Also, `array = list(input)` is much simpler than your explicit loop.

Comment: @Holloway: And `array[i] in ('s', 't', 'v', 'w', 'y', 'z')` can be shortened to `array[i] in 'stvwyz'`.

Comment: @Matthias, that would also be true if `array[i]` was 'st' or any substring. In this case it might be ok but they're not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't use `else if`. You must use `elif` instead.

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    if array[i] in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
        array[i] = array[i]
    else:
        if array[i] == "b" or array[i] == "c":
            vowel = "a"
        elif array[i] == "d" or array[i] == "f" or array[i] == "g":
            vowel = "e"
        elif array[i] == "h" or array[i] == "j" or array[i] == "k" or array[i] == "l":
            vowel = "i"
        elif array[i] == "m" or array[i] == "n" or array[i] == "p" or array[i] == "q" or array[i] == "r":
            vowel = "o"
        elif array[i] == "s" or array[i] == "t" or array[i] == "v" or array[i] == "w" or array[i] == "x" or array[i] == "y" or array[i] == "z":
            vowel = "u" 
        consenent = alphabet.index(array[i])


        array[i] = array[i] + vowel + alphabet[consenent + 1]
print ''.join(array)
```

Comment: your third block is still `else if`